# SQL CE 4 vs Files on a website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-ce

I am looking at moving all data loaded from files into drop downs, variable calculations, user state, Session Memory(hardcoded..),etc to be all loaded rather from SQL CE. Plus would be have it running in a MemCache or App Fabric layer but we don't have that luxury so we stuck with using Session or file loads to read the temp storage data. The data's too small to be kept in SQL Server as well as it's on a different machine on the network so compact edition seems to be a good option. It sounds like it's a viable option as you get a trimmed down db on your site versus files/session memory.

Comment: what's the question exactly ? Is SQL CE better than files on FS for storing some data ? What data exactly ?

Comment: Yes correct - data that would be language values,xml data,etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Session for temporary storage, but replace all code that uses filesystem for storage with SQL CE, with files on filesystem you have to have some sort of thread isolation for different users of your ASP.NET application and with SQL CE you got that out of the box.
If you have to have some sort of search on that data, searching bunch of files is not very feasible.

In general I would sure preferred SQL Server Compact than files.

Comment: Was thinking along the same lines, wasn't sure if i was on the right path.Thanks!